# Populate foreign key fields using data from form based on ModelForm

Tags: django, django-forms

I have set up my models as shown below:

Models.py

```
class Customer(models.Model):

    CustomerID = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    Name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    Mobile = models.CharField(max_length=15)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.CustomerID

class orderHistory(models.Model):

    BookingNumber = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    customer = models.ForeignKey(Customer)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.BookingNumber
```

I have also used ModelForm to setup my forms.py:

```
class customerForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Customer
        exclude = ['CustomerID']
```

The function in my views.py is something like this:

```
    if request.method == 'POST':
    form = customerForm(request.POST or None)
    # check whether it's valid:
    if form.is_valid():
        instance = form.save()
        if not instance.CustomerID:
            instance.CustomerID = 'DHOBI' + instance.Mobile

        instance.save()    
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/data/test')

    else:
        form = customerForm()
return render(request, "data/index.html",{'form':form})
```

My question is, after getting the data for the Customer model, how do I fill the data in BookingNumber in the database? I mean, if I want to set the booking number as Mobile + Today's Date and time. 
How do I do that.

Answer (score 0):

```
import datetime
bn = "%s-%s" % (instance.Mobile,str(datetime.datetime.now())
order_hist = orderHistory.objects.create(customer=instance, BookingNumber=bn)
```

Just note on naming of classes: give Classes Uppercase names and the attributes lowercase. You have it in reverse.